# sorting output to a csv

Tags: sorting, export-to-csv

I am trying to run a few whois for some domains and sort the wanted fields to a csv (i just need domain and Registrant Organization)

```
$domainname = get-content -Path "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\domain\domainname.txt"

foreach($domain in $domainname)
{
& ".\whois.exe" "$domain" | Select  "Domain Name:","Registrant Organization:" | 
export-csv "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\domain\domain-info.csv" 
}
```

the problem is - I am only getting Domain Name: Registrant Organization: in my CSV file -

if I use this -

```
& ".\whois.exe" "$domain" | Select-String -Pattern "Domain Name:","Registrant Organization:" | export-csv "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\domain\domain-info.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

i get the data that I want but not the labels or in a format to use